# How to get full Stack Trace on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

My api is returning an error but, is not showing a full stack trace:

```
2018-04-20T12:32:00.673008+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=PUT [...] status=500 bytes=243 protocol=https
```

I don't know why I'm getting this 500, since it works at development. I guess is about some missing add-on on Heroku or something like this, but I cant know if I don't get the 500 stack trace.

I already have a `config.log_level = :debug` at my `production.rb`.
Is it possible to see full stack trace at Heroku?

My project back-end uses Ruby on Rails 5.

Answer (score 1):

From command line run:

```
heroku logs -n 200
```

after -n number of lines you need .
check this out for [more information](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging).

Comment: I can access log by CL or web app, but the log is simply too poor. I have no details, so I dont know what is causing the error. Is there something that may be making the log so simple?  ( as seen in the question, it only tell me that an 500 ocurred)

Comment: Please Add full trace

Comment: I've already added all the trace in the question :/ Only omitted some attributes (path, host, request_id, fwd, dyno, connect and service). Any of these matter in this case? The trace, again:
`2018-04-20T12:32:00.673008+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=PUT [...] status=500 bytes=243 protocol=https`